# Don't understand some lines of code that reads a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is code which reads a file "jason.txt" and count how many of each “category” of each image there are.

The file data which I am using can be found at: http://www.practicepython.org/assets/Training_01.txt

```
counter_dict = {}

with open('jason.txt') as f:
   line = f.readline()

   while line:
     line = line[3:-26]

     if line in counter_dict:
         counter_dict[line] += 1

     else:
         counter_dict[line] = 1

     line = f.readline()

print(counter_dict)
```

Can someone explain what this line is doing:

```
line = line[3:-26]
```

And why are we using this line twice:

```
line = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example line from your file:

```
/a/abbey/sun_aqswjsnjlrfzzhiz.jpg
```

This gets read into the `line` variable by `line = f.readline()` so the while loop doesn't exit right away because of the empty line variable.

Then in the while loop `line = line[3:-26]` crops down the first 3 characters and the last 26 characters (because it is a line of a file, you need to count the return character at the end of each line, hence 26 instead of 25) so for this line your line variable will hold this: `abbey`.

The if statement in the while loop:

```
 if line in counter_dict:
         counter_dict[line] += 1

     else:
         counter_dict[line] = 1
```

If the value of the `line` variable which holds `abbey` at this point is found in the `counter_dict` than increments its value by 1 in the dictionary. If it is not found than adds it to the dictionary with value set to 1.

The last thing the while loop does is to get the next line from the file with `line = f.readline()`.

It will keep doing that until there is no next line and than it prints the resulting json file.

Comment: ty finally understood what that line[3:-26] does again thnks a lot

Answer (score 3):

line = line[3:-26], gets the line content from the 4th character to the end excluding the 26 last characters. It is used to extract the categoy name out of the file path from the jason.txt file.

The first line = f.readline(), is needed to init line before entering the while loop.
The second one in needed inside the loop to get and process the next line of the file, for each iteration.

Comment: i understand line[3:-26] gets content from the 4th character to the end excluding the 26 last characters but why use this ? is it even needed ?

Comment: We do not know the purpose of this piece of code ... this seems to get only the file path in the jason.txt file. It would be better to split the line on delimitters, i suppose.

Comment: i gave the purpose of this code at the very 1st line to take the data and count how many of each “category” of each image there are.

Comment: Right, so you can see that it is used to extract the categoy name out of the file path.